# Is it possible to use Nose to run one test multiple times, concurrently?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

Is it possible to use [`nose`](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose) to run **a single test** concurrently (across multiple processes) and aggregate the result in to a single pass/fail result?

We have the need to run the same test multiple times concurrently to ensure resource locking isn't being affected. If nose can't do this, is there a specific testing/design pattern to follow to achieve this?

Comment: So yes, it's possible to run a single test concurrently. Can you describe the aggregating into a single pass/fail in more detail? Do you want to mark a single test as 'run many times' and have others as 'run a single time' in the same suite? Should be easy if so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to [run tests concurrently with nose](http://packages.python.org/nose/doc_tests/test_multiprocess/multiprocess.html):

> Using the nose.plugin.multiprocess
>   plugin, you can parallelize a test run
>   across a configurable number of worker
>   processes. While this can speed up
>   CPU-bound test runs, it is mainly
>   useful for IO-bound tests that spend
>   most of their time waiting for data to
>   arrive from someplace else and can
>   benefit from parallelization.

I've adapted the plugin to run a single test in parallel as you want. Download from http://paste.pocoo.org/show/319470/ and save as `nose/plugins/repeat.py`. Then, in `nose/plugins/builtin.py`, add the line `('nose.plugins.repeat', 'RepeatMultiProcess'),` to `builtins`. Call like this:

```
c:\python27\python nose-1.0.0\selftest.py --repeat-processes=2 --repeat-times=3 test2.py
```

Note: setup/teardown support might be broken. If so, the fix is simple, see comment in line

Comment: You misunderstand - I need to run *one single test* multiple times concurrently.

Comment: I did not misunderstand, that is the built-in way to run "across multiple processes". I'm trying to figure out how to use it to run the same test in parallel.

Comment: Indeed my hack works, but somehow one test seems to always run only once. Debugging...

Comment: Both of your oginial source links are now broken.  Can you put the original code in a gist on github or something?

Answer (score 11):

This seems like something you want in the test definition itself because you want to assert on the aggregation of the results.  I would take a look at using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) in the test.  Create a pool to execute your code in parallel. You can use a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to aggregate the results.