# Looping through Python nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

I'm trying to follow [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611658/repeated-single-or-multiple-tests-with-nose) recommendation to looping through nosetests but it does not work.

Here is sample code (I need a class implementation):

```
class NoseTesting(unittest.TestCase):

    def _prepare_incredients(arg):
        """This is private method"""
        logger.info("The args are == {0}".format(arg))

    def test_make_icecream(self,):
        logger.info("Test case starting")
        for arg in ['sugar','cone']:
            yield (self._prepare_incredients,arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually read [the documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators) linked from the previous question:

> As in the example, test generators must yield tuples, the first
>   element of which must be a callable and the remaining elements the
>   arguments to be passed to the callable.

Instead, you are calling the method within your *"test generator"* and yielding the result (`None`, in this case). Switch the relevant line to:

```
yield (self._prepare_incredients, arg)
```

Comment: @user1050619 well how is the logging configured? Please provide a [mcve]